# deleting a row from a tableview

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to delete a row from a table view, but I am getting this error:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

this is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class VehiclesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: - Model
    var vehiclesStored = [Array<Vehicle>]() {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext

    // MARK: - Lifecycle methods

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        vehiclesStored.removeAll()
        vehiclesStored.insert(Vehicle.fetchVehicles(inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)!, at: 0)

        navigationItem.title = String(vehiclesStored[0].count) + " Vehicles"
        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return vehiclesStored.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return vehiclesStored[section].count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "vehiclesList", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        let vehicles = vehiclesStored[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = (vehicles.id_brand_model?.id_model?.brand)! + ", " + (vehicles.id_brand_model?.model)! + ", " + (vehicles.id_vehicle_type?.type)!
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyy hh:mm:ss"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(vehicles.id as! Int64) + ", " + vehicles.licence_plate! + ", " + (vehicles.id_color?.color_description)! + ", " + dateFormatter.string(from:vehicles.date as! Date)

        return cell
    }

    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            vehiclesStored[0].remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */


    // MARK: - Navigation

    @IBAction func unwindVehicleList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? VehicleAddViewController {
            if let vehicles = sourceViewController.vehicle {
                if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                    // Update an existing vehicle.
                    vehiclesStored[selectedIndexPath.section][selectedIndexPath.row] = vehicles
                    tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
                }
                else {
                    // Add a new vehicle.
                    vehiclesStored.removeAll()
                    vehiclesStored.insert(Vehicle.fetchVehicles(inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)!, at: 0)
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if segue.identifier != nil {
            if segue.identifier == "Show Detail" {
                let vehicleDetailViewController = segue.destination as! VehicleAddViewController

                // Get the cell that generated this segue.
                if let selectedVehicleCell = sender as? UITableViewCell {
                    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedVehicleCell)!
                    let selectedVehicle = vehiclesStored[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
                    vehicleDetailViewController.vehicle = selectedVehicle
                }
            }
            else if segue.identifier == "Add Item" {
                print("Adding new vehicle.")
            }
        }
    }


}
```

why is that?

Comment: Do you return in numberOfRows for section `vehiclesStored[section]`?

Comment: yes, return vehiclesStored[section].count, in override func tableView

Comment: please, can you show the entire code where you setup your tableview?

Comment: entire code added

Answer (score 0):

my problem was in the didSet of my var, it was reloading the data and no change was being detected at the time of deleting a row